# Perl: Check if current day is between two given days

Tags: perl

How would I find if the current day is between two other days.

This below code works if the two other days were something like Tues-Thursday

But what if I wanted to allow my user to give a range like Fri-Monday.

```
    my $timestamp = time;
    my $dow       = ( localtime($timestamp) )[6];

    my $range = '5-1'; # 5 being friday and 1 being monday 
    $range =~ m/(\d+)-(\d+)/;
    my ( $start, $end ) = ( $1, $2 );

    if ( $start >= 0 && $end <= 6 && $dow >= $start && $dow <= $end ) {
        print "$dow falls between your range";
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my $in = ( $start <= $end
   ? $start <= $dow && $dow <= $end
   : !( $end < $dow && $dow < $start )
);
```

or

```
my $in = ( $start <= $end
   ? $start <= $dow && $dow <= $end
   : $dow <= $end || $start <= $dow
);
```

Comment: Wow way less complicated then I was trying to make it. Thanks!